# undefined local variable or method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to implement a highchart that sums hours for a specified week. What it is currently doing is looking at my 'efforts' table and summing all records in that table. However I am trying to sum hours for a particular week, for the current user. I have the following snippet from my highcharts.html.erb.

```
 series: [{
                name: 'Hours',
           data: [<% @efforts.each do |effort| %>
[Date.UTC(<%= effort.week_commencing.strftime("%Y,%m-1,%d") %>),<%= Effort.sum(:hours).                                                                                          
where(:week_commencing => week_commencing, :user_id => current_user.id)%>],<% end %>]

        }]
    });
});
```

I have the full code available on pastebin http://pastebin.com/ifbQfR0i

Is there a way around this?

Updated: Error message

> NameError in Statistics#range
>
> Showing /home/Project/app/views/statistics/range.html.erb where line
>
> 115 raised:
>
> undefined local variable or method `week_commencing' for #<#:0x9fdadc8> Extracted source (around line #115):
>
> ```
>              name: 'Hours',
>      data: [<% @efforts.each do |effort| %>
>              [Date.UTC(<%= effort.week_commencing.strftime("%Y,%m-1,%d")
> ```
>
> %>),<%= Effort.sum(:hours).
>                                                                                             where(:week_commencing =>
>   week_commencing, :user_id => current_user.id)%>],<% end %>]
>         }]  });  });

**Efforts.rb**

```
== Schema Information

 Table name: efforts

  id              :integer(4)      not null, primary key
  project_task_id :integer(4)
  user_id         :integer(4)
  week_commencing :date
  hours           :float
  created_at      :datetime
  updated_at      :datetime
```

Comment: Please include the full error message in your question

Comment: Added the error message, please see my post

Comment: `where(:week_commencing => week_commencing...` - what is `week_commencing`?

Comment: I really don't think the template is the right place for this logic, either--it'd be way easier to test/debug/etc. if it was somewhere more appropriate.

Comment: @Zabba week_commencing is a attribute in a table 'efforts. I have updated my post to show what my efforts table. I have updated my post further

Comment: I managed to fix it partially, it should've been Effort.sum(:hours). where(:week_commencing => effort.week_commencing, :user_id => current_user.id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure, but shouldn't it be:

```
%>),<%= Effort.sum(:hours). where(:week_commencing => effort.week_commencing, :user_id => current_user.id)%>],<% end %>] }] }); });
```

instead of

```
%>),<%= Effort.sum(:hours). where(:week_commencing => week_commencing, :user_id => current_user.id)%>],<% end %>] }] }); });
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, however I commented already saying that I was missing the 'effort' in front of week_commencing. However I now get the following error: `undefined method `where' for 262.0:Float` which I have never come across before

Comment: It seems to me that the order of the methods is wrong. You should first use where and then sum `Effort.where(...).sum(:hours)`, because the sum method does not return an ActiveRelation object